# permission denied for reading directory owned by the same user

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have two users on a Ubuntu machine. One of them is in sudoers list, while the other is not. I create a directory in first user's home directory. Then I change the ownership of this directory to the other user. Now when I switch to the other user and try to read this directory, it says permission denied.

I used `chown` with `-R` so it applied to everything inside the directory.

The `ls -l` shows this

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 lfs  lfs   4096 Mar 23 02:07 sources
```

`lfs` being the second user.

Comment: Does the parent directories of the "source" directory have execute permissions for the other user?

Comment: Concur with @Kusalananda - check the entire tree leading up to that directory. Chances are that's why you're getting locked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a follow-up to @Kusalananda 's question in the comment associated with your question above.

Suppose that you have two users, `user1` and `user2`.  Suppose that `user1` has a home directory `/home/user1`.  Now suppose that in the home directory of `user1` you create a directory owned by `user2`, say `/home/user1/sources`, can `user2` access that directory?

In order for `user2` to be able to access `/home/user1/sources`, then `user2` needs to have `x` (traverse) permission on each directory from root, up to and including the `sources` directory:

```
$ ls -ld /
dr-xr-xr-x 31 root root 4096 Feb 28 11:37 /
         ^ Check (this will almost always be OK)

$ ls -ld /home
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Feb 28  11:38 /home
         ^ Check (this will almost always be OK)

$ ls -ld /home/user1
drwx------ 9 user1 group1 4096 Mar 21 00:36 /home/user1
      ^  ^ In this case, no, user2 cannot traverse here

$ ls -ld /home/user1/sources
drwxr-xr-x 9 user2 group2 4096 Mar 21 00:36 /home/user1/sources
   ^ Check
```

In this example, because `user2` cannot traverse into `/home/user1`, `user2` cannot access `/home/user1/sources` (even though `user2` owns that directory).

In your question you said that the `sources` directory is in the home directory of the first user.  My guess is that the second user can't access the first user's home directory.

You might consider putting the `sources` directory somewhere outside of the user's home directory.

Comment: Thank you. :) i had to use /mnt to create the sources for user lfs to be able to read.